# Replacing composite primary key with sequential id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a table with a composite primary key. I want to create a migration that removes that primary key and introduces a new column 'id' that is sequential and will become the new primary key.

```
Schema::table('cart_line', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('cart_line_pkey');
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->primary('id');
});
```

This code throws the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P16]: Invalid table definition: 7 ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "cart_line" are not allowed (SQL: alter table "cart_line" add primary key ("id"))
```

If I directly execute the following SQL, the primary key is being dropped and the code above executes without error:

```
ALTER TABLE cart_line DROP CONSTRAINT cart_line_pkey;
```

That's why I tried

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE cart_line DROP CONSTRAINT cart_line_pkey;');

Schema::table('cart_line', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->primary('id');
});
```

but the the same error is thrown. The old primary key is not dropped, but there is no error until it tries to create the new one.

I'm using laravel 5.5 and postgres 9.6

Comment: *$table->increments('id');* is already a primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in separate closures, so try this:

```
Schema::table('cart_line', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('cart_line_pkey');
});

Schema::table('cart_line', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

The problem is the transaction has not committed yet, so making it two transactions should solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Remove `$table->primary('id')` *because* `$table->increments('id')`makes the id column **primary key**

```
Schema::table('cart_line', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('cart_line_pkey');
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Comment: As it turns out it was combination of this and the problem that btl described. I accept the other answer because it contains the correct code.